# Windows Server 2019 install to intel RST Raid 1 volume not showing up in installer

Tags: raid, windows-server-2019

I have an asrock rack Z490D4U-2L2T motherboard (working with a Intel 11700K) that supports Intel RST (BIOS reports driver version as 18.31.0.5166). I have two Samsung 870 evo SSDs that I want to put in RAID 1 and install Windows Server 2019 to them.

In the bios, I have switched the SATA mode selection to `Intel RST Premium with Intel Optane System Acceleration (RAID Mode)`. Both drives do show up in the bios.
In the RST specific bios section, I select `Create RAID volume`, put them in RAID 1 and select create.

[image: BIOS Storage Configuration]
[image: BIOS RST Configuration]
[image: BIOS Raid 1 Volume]

Everything seems to be working, I save and reboot into the Windows Server installer. When I get to the storage selection screen, it is blank.

I went to [Intel RST Driver Installation Software](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/download/19512/intel-rapid-storage-technology-driver-installation-software-with-intel-optane-memory-10th-and-11th-gen-platforms.html) and downloaded the two zip files, and extracted their contents to a usb drive. I plug the USB drive in, and the Windows installer cannot find any drivers.

[image: Windows Installer Disk Selection]
[image: Windows Installer Driver Selection]
[image: Driver USB Contents]

I am unfamiliar with advanced windows installs, so I think maybe I am missing a step somewhere? Did I not download the correct drivers?

Is it even possible to boot off an Intel RST Raid volume with windows server?

Comment: Why are you using consumer HW as a server? Also never use 'softraid', it'll bite you down the line.

Comment: I'm using consumer hardware as the workload for this particular server is not suited for hp/dell servers with xeons or even xeon golds. Too slow. And yes I am aware of software raid not being the best. But the option was either a sketchy 3.5 to dual 2.5" raid enclosure or software raid.

Comment: Unless you can recommend a high quality standalone raid controller (doesn't use a pcie slot) then I'm really stuck with software raid. (I am open to suggestions, but my requirements are very strict unfortunately)

Comment: I've been thinking, maybe instead of software raid, a better solution is to use the second disk as a hot spare and make daily full drive clones of the primary disk to it. This way, the primary disk failing is simple to recover from by changing the boot order in the bios. (this servers application is not critical and sustain downtime)

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunatly, Intel drops RST support for Windows Server 2019. The driver you have downloaded is only for 2016.

Look closer https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/download/15667/intel-rapid-storage-technology-intel-rst-user-interface-and-driver.html

> Windows 10, 64-bit*, Windows Server 2016 family* Size: 3.7 MB SHA1:
> EF7FAE2C67B5586F951E33C97B2B37D0AC75D485